# Submit HTML form data to IFTTT webhook with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webhooks, ifttt

I have a HTML form. When submitting the form I would like to send the data to an IFTTT webhook.
I tried two options, but it seems like they are not working.

HTML submit button:

```
<li class="buttons"><input name="klantnummer" type="hidden" value="1234567890" />
<button onclick="sendToIFTTT123()">Verstuur</button></li>
```

The first code:

```
<script> function sendToIFTTT123(){
var url = "https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/[event]/with/key/[key]";
var text = {"value 1" : document.getElementById("element_2_1").value + " - " + document.getElementById("element_2_2").value + " - " +       document.getElementById("element_2_3").value};
$.ajax({
    data: 'payload=' + JSON.stringify({
        "text": text
    }),
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: url
});
}

</script>
```

Second code:

```
 <script>
    function sendToIFTTT() {
    var content = {"value1" : document.getElementById("element_2_1").value + " - " + document.getElementById("element_2_2").value + " - " +         document.getElementById("element_2_3").value};
    var url = "https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/[event]/with/key/[key]";
    var options =  {
     "method" : "post",
     "contentType" : "application/json",
     "payload" : JSON.stringify(content)
  };
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  }</script>
```

Anyone any idea who to get this working?

Comment: You should communicate with IFTTT via a backend programming language so you don't expose your key.

Comment: @bashaus I don't get it.. I have my own key... And I think my key is not my mistake, but something else in the code.

Comment: "but it seems like they are not working" what exactly are the symptoms. Any errors?

Comment: @phuzi no errors shown, but my applets on ifttt is not triggert, so I assume my way of sending my data to the ifttt trigger is incorrect.